# How do I install Windows 8.1 Pro on a Mac using bootcamp?

Tags: windows-8.1, iso-image, boot-camp

I bought Windows 8.1 Pro from the Microsoft store with student discount. All I got was a product key and a download named "OSGS14-WindowsSetupBox-32bitand64bit-English-4141408.exe".

I can't open the .exe file. I can only unzip it. I'm assuming that on Windows that is a downloader that would download an ISO of windows 8.1 Pro for me. Bootcamp requires me to have an ISO file on a USB or DVD in order to work but I can't use the download Microsoft gave me. There is no direct link to download a Windows 8.1 Pro ISO file.

What do I do now?

Comment: Use a Windows Virtual Machine to download the .iso and transfer it to the host operating system.

Comment: @Ramhound Even if I download a virtualization software like VMware (which I just downloaded) don't I need to somehow install Windows on it?

Comment: Yes;  Microsoft offers nearly every version of Windows for every virtual machine for free to test IE.  They are trial installation but will allow you to download the .iso